# Storing XML in SQL Server 2005

Tags: .net, xml, sql-server-2005

I have generated an xml using C# for my current project and I want to save this xml in my database (SQL Server 2005).

If I save the `XmlDocument` as datatype `xml` in SQL Server 2005, will it degrade performance??? Which is the good method to save the xml?

Comment: Be more specific. What performance are you worried about? Do you plan on doing queries over the XML data? Does the XML have a schema (which can influence the performance and indexing of XML data)?

Comment: **WHICH** performance are you afraid of?? The normal SQL Server queries? XML specific queries? Performance of your C# project??? WHAT??

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345118(v=sql.90).aspx

For perfomance related info read the section on XML indexes. As a general rule I would say it is a good idea to use the datatype designed to hold the type of data you want to store unless you can find a specific reason in your particular case that would make some other type a better choice.